# How to run tox from github actions

Tags: python-3.x, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, tox

I am new to tox and GitHub actions, and I am looking for a simple way to make them work together. I wrote this [simple workflow](https://github.com/erelsgl/fairpy/blob/master/.github/workflows/pythonpackage.yml):

```
name: Python package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install tox
      run: pip install tox
    - name: Run tox
      run: tox
```

which just installs tox and then runs it. But when I [run this workflow](https://github.com/erelsgl/fairpy/runs/367865577), the tox installation works fine, but the run command returns an error:

```
tox: command not found
```

What is the correct way to run tox from a GitHub action?

Comment: tox dev seem to have created [something for this](https://github.com/tox-dev/gh-action-tox), but it's poorly documented and hasn't been edited in a year

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Extend from the comment:)

[Github Actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-python-with-github-actions#running-tests-with-tox) docs use `actions/setup-python@v2`:

```
- name: Setup Python
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
```

Also you can try `python -m tox`.

Comment: Use of "actions/setup-python@v2" is recommended now.

Comment: @ymyzk Thanks, the answer is updated! I see the tag `v2.2.2` at https://github.com/actions/setup-python/tags :-)

Comment: still get the same error on setup-python@v4

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [tox-gh-actions](https://github.com/ymyzk/tox-gh-actions).

In your workflow file:

```
 steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    uses: actions/setup-python@v2
    with:
      python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install tox tox-gh-actions
  - name: Test with tox
    run: tox
```

In your tox.ini (other config formats work too):

```
[gh-actions]
python = 
  3.8: py38
```

Comment: I think it's valuable to learn about tox-gh-actions, but this answer could elaborate on what problem that tool solves. E.g. Not so much about running tox, but about mapping the GA version matrix to tox envs.

Comment: The "Test with tox" section of the workflow file in the example accurately portrays how to actually run the testing using Tox in GitHub Actions. So it's rather complete!